# TO_PURE_TEXT with cell referencing doesn't filter double quotes against documentation

Tags: regex, google-sheets, string-formatting, google-sheets-formula, number-formatting

I want to get a clean number from a string like "123.45". On using of `=TO_PURE_TEXT(C10)` it doesn't work for me,

[image]

against an [example from the documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094243). An absolute referencing doesn't help.

But, if i use no cell referencing, but direct input, like `=TO_PURE_TEXT("123.45")` the input is correct, as expected without quotes.

Is it a kind of bug, or do i really do something wrong? How can i get this work with the cell referencing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all you need is:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(C10, """", )*1
```

or:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(C10, """", )*1
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to whether it's a bug.  Does seem odd, but this should work for now:

```
=1*SUBSTITUTE(C10,CHAR(34),"")
```

Comment: Thank you, I go the way with `=VALUE(REGEXREPLACE(C10, "[^0-9.]+", "")))` - but i don't want to make simple things complicated. Thats why i want to use this simple beautiful `TO_PURE_NUMBER`